# inserting in front of linked list without a dummy node

Tags: c

I'm trying to insert in the front of a linked list which is sorted by node-> name and I do not have a dummy node in the filesystem-> curr->subdir

```
typedef struct Unix{

  struct Node *curr;
  struct Node *root;


}Unix;

typedef struct Node{

  struct Node *next;
  struct Node *subdir;
  struct Node *parent;
  char *name;
  char *field;

}Node;
```

below is me inserting into the linked list sorted by names

```
/* iter is a node used to traverse LL */

if(iter-> next == NULL && strcmp(iter->name, arg) > 0){
      if(iter == filesystem-> curr-> subdir){
/* error occurs when placing node in the front of the list */
    temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    temp-> parent = filesystem-> curr-> subdir-> parent;
    temp-> subdir = NULL;
    temp-> name = malloc(strlen(filesystem->curr->subdir->name) + 1);
    strcpy(temp-> name, filesystem-> curr-> subdir-> name);
    temp-> next = NULL;

/* add is the node that's being inserted */
    add-> next = temp;

    filesystem-> curr->subdir = add;
```

Error occurs when attempting to place add as the first node in filesystem-> curr-> subdir and moving the previous subdir node to be add-> next.

EDIT: the program is a basic simulation of a unix machine.

Comment: Actually __all__ your string buffers are one byte to small. There are three of them in your code. You need one more byte for the NUL string terminator.

Comment: You should show us a [mcve]. Especially the code that calls `mkdir` may be wrong as well.

Answer (score 1):

That's where I'd start to suspect of a bug (right at the beginning of your code):

```
add-> parent = malloc(sizeof(Node));
add-> parent = filesystem-> curr;
```

You're assigning `add-> parent` twice, which means that it will obviously attain the latter assignment, while the former assignment "goes wasted".

In addition to a memory leak in your program (since you will not be able to free this allocated block of memory), there's a good chance that setting `add-> parent` to that value is not what you had in mind.

Comment: the parent is not used in this function but is used in others and works fine. My problem is when inserting a node that will be the first within the linked list of filesystem->curr-> subdir. For example, if B was in the front as the node that is in filesystem-> curr-> subdir, and I attempt to insert A, I am unable to make A-> next be B and set filesystem-> curr-> subdir equal to A

Comment: While this is true, it's not the only problem in his code.

Comment: @MelvinMolina `add-> parent = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  add-> parent = filesystem-> curr;` is conceptually wrong. It's like writing `int x; x = 12 ; x = 34;`

Comment: @Jabberwocky you are correct. I've made the change. I'd not yet looked into any memory leakage, but this is definitely a case of that happening.

Comment: @MelvinMolina it's not so much a matter of memory leaking but rather about what should go into `add-> parent`. Is it `malloc(sizeof(Node));` or `filesystem->curr`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky add-> parent is the filesystem-> curr.

Comment: @MelvinMolina please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59428509/edit) your question and show a [mcve]. And read the comments to your question, they show other bugs.

Comment: @Jabberwocky is this better

Comment: @MelvinMolina I don't know, you completely changed your code and it's still not an [mcve]

Comment: @Jabberwocky to be reproducible I'd need to provide another function. My error is entirely in inserting as the first node in subdir, and moving the previous first node to be add-> next and filesystem-> curr-> subdir to be equal to add.